# An error occurred while saving the cms page in magento back-end

Tags: error, cms

When i am creating new cms page at that time it give error "An error occurred while saving the page." but old cms pages i can save so please help me to solve this issue

Thank You.

Comment: This means normally that an exception is thrown and catched. There should be some information in the log files.

Comment: have you add any things in layout field(XML)

Comment: Have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/158 and see if you can find the complete error message.